# Não consigo inserir dados no banco de dados

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, mariadb

A pagina carrega tudo certo , porem mesmo assim as colunas ficam vazias no banco

{

```
<?php



$servername = "localhost";
$database = "login";
$username = "root";
$passwd = "odair";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username ,$passwd , $database);

$nome = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["nome"]);
$sobrenome = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["sobrenome"]);
$nascimento = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["bday"]);
$genero = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["gender"]);



$sql = "INSERT INTO 'login'.'dados' ('nome', 'sobrenome','bday','gender') VALUES ('{$nome}', '{$sobrenome}','{$nascimento}','{$genero}'";

mysqli_query($conn , $sql);
mysqli_close($conn);





?>}
```

Comment: tenta pegar exatamente como está no código e substituir por valores reais em um SGBD(workbench) e ve se está inserindo.

Comment: Tentei sem as chaves , e tentei inserir valores reais sem ser das variaveis tbm, mas sem sucesso..

Comment: $sql = "INSERT INTO `login`.`dados` (`nome`, `sobrenome`, `bday`, `gender`) VALUES ('odair', 'silva', '2019-02-25', 'male')";

Dessa forma deu certo... mas como posso passar os valores das variaveis ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO login.dados (nome, sobrenome, bday, gender) VALUES ('$nome', '$sobrenome', '$nascimento', '$genero')";
```

Comment: PERFEITO... era o uso das aspas simples ao informar os nomes das colunas..